# ¿Cómo ordenar un ArrayList en Java Android?

Tags: java, android

¿Cómo se hace para ordenar un `List` con tipo personalizado en Java de Android?

Las listas simples uso `Collections.sort(lista)` pero de tipo personalizado no ser como especificar que campo debe tener en cuenta para ordenar la lista.

Tengo lo siguiente creado

**Classe Person.java**

```
public class Person {
    String gender;
    String name;
    int age;
    double height;
    double weight;

   public Person(String gender, String name, int age, double height, double weight) {
        this.gender = gender;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
   }

//Getters
   public String getGender() {
       return this.gender;
   }
   public String getName() {
       return this.name;
   }
   public int getAge() {
       return this.age;
   }
   public double getHeight() {
       return this.height;
   }
   public double getWeight() {
       return this.weight;
   }
}
```

**Llenar la lista**

```
List<person> people = new ArrayList<>();
people.add(new Person("F","Alice", 15, 160, 48));
people.add(new Person("F","Karen", 18, 140, 45));
people.add(new Person("M","Bob", 8, 90, 30));
people.add(new Person("M","John", 40, 180, 78));
```

Me falta saber como ordenar la lista `people` por nombre y otro agrupando (altura,peso,edad)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Necesitas hacer el `sort` con un Comparador personalizado.

El comparador por nombre sería el siguiente :

```
class ComparadorPersonas implements Comparator<Person> {
  public int compare(Person a, Person b) {
    return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
  }
}
```

El método `compare` debe devolver un negativo si `a` se considera menor que `b`. 0 si se consideran iguales. Y un positivo si `a` se considera mayor que `b`.

Lo usarías así :

```
Collections.sort(people, new ComparadorPersonas());
```

Para ordenar con otro criterio crea otro comparador.

Comment: Gracias, con eso mirare si me sale lo de agrupar, teniendo más campos en cuenta

Answer (score 3):

Si utilizas [RetroLambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda), una librería que porta algunas características de Java 8 (como lambdas y try with resources) a versiones anteriores, puedes usar Lambdas, con lo cual se reduce el código y se hace más legible.

```
Comparator<Person> byName = (p1, p2) -> p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
List<Person> persons = persons.stream().sorted(byName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Eso de que las lambdas son más legibles es muy discutible. Pero no afecta a que te de +1.